# request header not set to text/event-stream for Eventsource calls

Tags: html, node.js, server-sent-events

I have the following Eventsource.

```
 var source = new EventSource('/events');
    source.onmessage = function(e) {
      document.body.innerHTML += e.data + '<br>';
    };
```

The problem is, the Accept request header is automatically set to `text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8`.

In node.js i'm handling the request with the following condition.

```
if (req.headers.accept && req.headers.accept != 'text/event-stream') {..}
```

Because of this im unable to stream data.
Please let me know how to set accept request header to text/event-stream while calling EventSource('/events');

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this:

```
if(req.url == '/events'){
    res.writeHead(200,{'content-type':'text/event-stream'});
    //Your sse code here...
    sendMsg('some data...');
}
```

It's more straightforward and you don't need to deal with the request header problem anymore.

Answer (score 0):

you can not do this
the browser sets Accept header for you

an EventSource object makes request with "text/event-stream" accept header under Chrome, Firefox and Opera 
check, that you are handling the right request